# Premium memberships within ExpressionEngine?

Tags: payment-gateway, membership, expressionengine

I've been tasked with implementing premium memberships within an ExpressionEngine site. The platform has been chosen by the client, and I'm not allowed plugins, so please no answers of, "You'd be better using x plugin."

What I'm wanting to do is create an add-on that intercepts the built-in member registration to insert a payment gateway form in between the visitor entering their details, and the member actually going into the database.

I've had a look and it seems it may be possible with the use of hooks (hence going the add-on route), but I'm not sure how I'd hold the details, do the payment with the third-party payment gateway, and then insert the data upon return to the ExpressionEngine site?

Has any one done any thing similar before? Is this possible? I'm a pretty proficient PHP developer (just not an expert in ExpressionEngine) so feel free to get technical.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to explore why you can't add third party add-ons, but it's fine to write your own?!?

Extensions use hooks:
http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/development/extensions.html

But a module will allow for front end and backend interface which might be required:
http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/development/module_tutorial.html

You'd need to create a database on install to store the users details prior to going to the gateway. Then on return from the gateway, there should be some sort of identifier you sent to the gateway that is unique and you can use to lookup in the database. You could then create the user.  Alas EE doesn't offer a members API at the moment, although I believe it is in the pipeline. So you'd need to then add the member details to the appropriate database tables.

I'd suggest an approach of creating a user natively in EE:
http://expressionengine.com/wiki/Standalone_Registration_Form
Therefore storing it correctly within the EE database (and therefore they're logged in and a unique member ID, email, etc all stored and allocated). But you have them in a pending member group (you'll need to use hooks to allocate this I believe). Once you've got back from the payment gateway, you can then change their member group to active and validate their membership.  This way you're not having to double up on the whole member registration and storage of data.

See - managed to respond without suggesting http://www.membrr.com at all.  Doh!

Comment: Not using third-party modules for a number of reasons. Want as little dependencies as possible, and I want to learn how extensions work myself so I can write them.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the native Simple Commerce module to accept payment and move members to a different member group upon receipt of payment. It allows for recurring payments.  Then you could map templates to that specific member group so only they would see the content.

It's all PayPal however.

Comment: Hi Michael. Sounds interesting. Have you got any resources handy that outlines this?